# Looking for a way to exclude certain items from my query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query I'm running daily and I'd like to exclude certain items from this query that I've already identified as not wanting to see without adding another table to the database. Below is my attempt at this, which works with one `TaskID` but not multiple `TaskID`s as I'm trying to do.

I feel its also important to note that this list could grow into roughly 150 ID's but not necessarily over 200 if that makes a difference. Obviously the way I did it is not the best way. Can anyone recommend the best way to accomplish this?

Direct question: what is the best way to exclude a large number of `TaskID`'s from the below query without creating another table?

```
SELECT  
    TaskID, MAX(timeended) AS 'Last Run' 
FROM
    [moveitautomationagain].[dbo].taskruns
WHERE
    TaskID <> 222300 OR TaskID <> 103439128
GROUP BY
    TaskID
HAVING
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, MAX(timeended), SYSDATETIME()) > 24
```

Comment: The *best way* to handle such a large number of "exceptions" **would be** to put them into a separate table, really.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your query you need `AND` not `OR`. However I would use `NOT IN` i.e.

```
where TaskID not in (222300, 103439128)
```

Comment: I love that this works and that my issue was as easy as a syntax problem, is there a better way to do this with 100 potential exclusions though?

Comment: Yes  a table. Which you resist.

Comment: Only if you have a more generic way to identify them :) e.g. a column called `ignore` then you could have `where ignore = 0`